# The copyright statement on the Contests site contains an `Â` character

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, contest

The copyright statement on the [Contests site](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos) appears to contain an additional `Â` character before the copyright symbol:

```
<p>
  site design / logo Â© 2018 Stack Exchange, Inc; [...]
</p>
```

[image: Edge, Firefox and Chrome viewing the site]

This is typically caused by a mis-encoded UTF symbol somewhere in the rendering chain.

Comment: I can reproduce in Edge, as above.

Comment: @Paweł while at it, can you also add favicon, so that the site won't show blank in the browser tabs?

Comment: @Paweł almost a month later... is it still planned? This tag means "a developer is working on a fix" as far as I can tell, if it's just sitting in a drawer waiting, better not use any tag since it can wait for long years, creating false hopes. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard fix was waiting in repo, but no one hit "build" button after that until now...

Comment: @Paweł can't you hit that "build" button yourself? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for reporting this bug. As you mentioned, it was caused by a mis-encoded UTF symbol in the footer. It should be fixed now.